# Azure Application Gateway : How to add authorization certificate to httpsettings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli

The following command is in powershell, where it adds the authorization certificate along with new `httpsettings`.

```
$poolSetting = New-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name 'setting01' -Port 443 -Protocol Https -CookieBasedAffinity Enabled -AuthenticationCertificates $authcert
```

How can we do this via `az` CLI (Azure CLI)? In there I'm not able to find the `AuthenticationCertificates` attribute.

Comment: I think --cert-file parameter in the cli command is same AuthenticationCertificates parameter

Comment: Nope it is for SSL certificate to be attached  to frontend listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a application gateway, there is no such command. But you could use `az network application-gateway http-settings update` to modify it.

See this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4910).

```
az network application-gateway http-settings create  --gateway-name yugangw-ag-1 -g yugangw-ag  --port 443 -n yugangw-ag-1-be-http-settings  --protocol https
az network application-gateway auth-cert create --cert-file d:\temp\TestCert.cer --gateway-name yugangw-ag-1 -n yugangw-ag-1-auth-cert -g yugangw-ag
az network application-gateway http-settings update  --gateway-name yugangw-ag-1 -g yugangw-ag -n yugangw-ag-1-be-http-settings --add authenticationCertificates id="/subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-cb9272f09590/resourceGroups/yugangw-ag/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/yugangw-ag-1/authenticationCertificates/yugangw-ag-1-auth-cert"
```

Comment: Just give me some time to try this shenbao

Comment: Placed it on deployment lets see what happens

Comment: Apologies for replying late but you are a life saver